# What to do about the Spanish Wikipedia page about Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I understand that this maybe does not directly relate to SO as a Q&A site, but rather to the integrity of the company. I was looking for the Stack Overflow Wikipedia page, and I discovered that a prankster who has been terrorizing the Parenting Stack Exchange was terrorizing the Wikipedia page. This should be addressed ASAP. Stack Overflow is a friendly community and I fear people seeing this will think otherwise. Does anyone have a backup of what the page previously said, and can they switch it back?

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow

Comment: Looks like Wikipedia's problem, not ours. We're already handling our own trolls here, we should probably let them handle their own trolls there.

Comment: Ah, okay! So what do I do about this post? Should I just remove it?

Comment: @Eamonn As I recall, anybody could roll back that Wikipedia page to a pre-defacement state. That is, *you* could do it.

Comment: Oh okay! I guess that makes a lot of sense. I'll look into doing it, and come back here if I need some direction or if I successfully roll it back. I'm unfamiliar with the details of editing Wikipedia.

Comment: Apologies, but the page is in Spanish and even with the (somewhat) aid of Google Translate I was unable to find a way to edit the page. If anyone here speaks Spanish and is familiar with editing on Wikipedia, I'm sure we'd all greatly appreciate it if you were to help us out.

Comment: [status-completed]

Comment: Thanks @Bart! Can someone close this question? I see no need for it to remain open, but I feel it should remain undeleted in the case of this problem presenting itself again.

Comment: Wikipedia [Vandalismo en curso](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Vandalismo_en_curso). (Administrator intervention in vandalism)